# docker sed arg variable not being used

Tags: docker, sed

I have a simple dockerfile which uses sed to replace variable in a file. The variable is being set from Dockerfile arg. However, it doesn't get used.

```
FROM php:7.4-cli
ARG VERSION=3.2
RUN sed -in '/<\/body>/i <version="${VERSION}">' /var/www/readme.xml
```

```
the output is:
<version="${VERSION}">
```

expected output needs to be:

```
<version="3.2">
```

Comment: Is that the entire Dockerfile? That base image does not have a `/var/www/readme.xml` file. Can you share what the `readme.xml` file looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your quotes to be `"/<\/body>/i <version=\"${VERSION}\">"`. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.